# Call Tiny C Compiler from a C++ code

Tags: c++, c, compiler-construction

I'm trying to compile a C code in a file from a program in C++. When I run my program it call the Tiny C Compiler and generate a dll from the compilation of c code. 
I tried to do it by a lot of ways but I couldn't. Did anyone already do something like this?

Thanks

Comment: Calling C code from C++ is generally not a problem at all. Please be more specific - how exactly did you try it (preferably post relevant sample code to demonstrate what you did), and how exactly it didn't work.

Comment: Sounds like the question is how to launch an executable to compile C code from C++, not how to call the C code from C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What platform are you on?

On most platforms, you can use the C standard library's `system()` function to launch a separate process from your C++ program.

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
   system ("tcc -o myproc a.c");
   return 0;
}
```

This will block until the spawned process exits.

On Windows, if you're not concerned about portability, you can use [`CreateProcess()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682425%28VS.85%29.aspx).